# C memory allocation affects char array length

Tags: c, arrays, memory, allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  //Step 1
  char *key = malloc(10000);
  int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int));
  free(arr);
  free(key);

  //Step 2
  char *msg = malloc(10000);
  printf("Size: %zu \n", strlen(msg)); 
  free(msg);

  return 0;
}
```

Could someone explain this:

- if I execute both step 1 and 2, the length of msg will be 6, sometimes 4
- if I exectue both step 1 and 2, but without the allocation and freeing of key, the length is 0
- if I execute only step 2, the length of msg will be 0

why does the allocation of the int and key array affect the length of a char array?
I realize that strlen requires a '\0' char, but why does it behave different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char *msg = malloc(10000);
printf("Size: %zu \n", strlen(msg));
```

`msg` is allocated, but not initialized, so it is undefined behavior to call `strlen(msg)`.

In your cases, perhaps it just happens that in the uninitialized memory allocated by `malloc`, the first `0` appeared at different places.

Answer (score 1):

Allocation and initialization are different things. In your program, you are allocating memory (with malloc), but you are never initializing it. The C language makes no guarantees about the contents of un-initialized heap-space memory.

In practice, the memory's contents will not be random, but it will take the value of whatever was in that place in memory previous to you allocating it. But, don't rely on any particular behavior you observe, as it could (and will) change from run-to-run or from day-to-day.

Answer (score 0):

[strlen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) assumes a null-terminated string.  If you don't initialize your array, then all bets are off.  This is called ["undefined behavior"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

One easy fix is to use [calloc()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/calloc), which initializes all bytes to "zero".

Comment: `calloc`: And is also a clear case of needless zeroing of memory (setting the first byte to 0 is enough).